# Statistical test with proportions and infinite population.

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am stuck with this problem:

The proportion of a random sample of 400 elements from an infinite population is 0.49215. With the level of significance 5$\%$ test if the sample comes from a population for which the proportion equals 0.51.

I got this solution:

\begin{align*}
H_0:&\ p=0.51\\
H_1:&\ p\neq 0.51
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
n&=400\\
p_0&=0.51\\
1-p_0&=1-0.51=0.49\\
\hat{p}&=0.49215\\
\alpha&=0.05\\
z_{\alpha /2}&=1.96\qquad \text{(two-sided test)}\\
\sqrt{\frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}&=\sqrt{\frac{0.51\cdot 0.49}{400}}=0.024995
\end{align*}
Using $z$-test:
\begin{align*}
z&=\frac{\hat{p}-p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}}=\frac{0.49215-0.51}{0.024995}=-0.714143\\ \\
|z|&=0.714143<z_{\alpha /2}=1.96 \Longrightarrow \ \ \text{accepted}\ H_0
\end{align*}

Comment: Ignore the "infinite population" part and proceed like you would any test of proportions.

Comment: Thanks. After I try, I will post my solution

Comment: Your method looks fine. I didn't check your arithmetic. // Another way to look at this is that a 95% CI has a margin of error about $M =  .044$ and 0.51 is well within $0.492 \pm M.$ // Rough rule of thumb often used by pollsters: when $p$ is near .5 the 95% margin of error is about $\pm 1/\sqrt{n}.$

Comment: I just ask to learn about the method. What does "*proportion of a random sample of 400 elements from an infinite population is 0.49215*" means ? Does it mean that 400 elements from an infinite population represents 0.49125 of the total population ? Therefore the population isn't infinite ! I thus don't understand "*the sample comes from a population for which the proportion equals 0.51.*" neither.